# Remove placeholder text from one specific text box element using jQuery on button click

Tags: jquery, html

I have a text box element with a placeholder called 'housenumber'.

At present, when the search button is pressed on my form, the text 'housenumber' is passed into my SQL query instead of nothing (null/blank).

Can somebody please provide the jQuery to remove the 'housenumber' placeholder text so my textbox is clear if nothing is entered and the search button is hit?

Please note, the search button is NOT a form submit button, just a jQuery click event button.

Comment: Please do not ask [do you haz teh codez](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/129950/how-to-avoid-do-you-haz-teh-codez-situations) type questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    if ($("#input").val()=="housenumber") {
        $("#input").val("");
    }
});
```

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks.